# Installing hasking via "install haskell-platform" on Linux - cabal isn't installed

Tags: linux, haskell

I installed haskell on Ubuntu 14 by:

```
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

But cabal hasn't been installed for some reason:

```
$ cabal --version
-bash: /home/me123/.cabal/bin/cabal: No such file or directory
```

And there's no

```
$ ls /home/alex/.cabal
ls: cannot access /home/me123/.cabal: No such file or directory
```

So how can install it or where can I find it if it's already installed?

P.S.
It was installed previously but for some reason I deleted it by apt-get remove ghc and haskell-plathorm. So I want to install everything all over again.

Comment: That first error message (mentioning a specific directory) is a bit suspicious. Is that the exact command you're running? Do you have any shell aliases for `cabal`? What does `type -a cabal` say?

Comment: @DanielWagner, what can it say if cabal isn't installed?

Comment: It is not clear to me that cabal isn't installed. I can suggest several alternative explanations for the evidence you've provided so far. Please give the output requested, so that we can narrow down the problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner, $ type -a cabal
cabal is /usr/bin/cabal`

Comment: That's a good sign. Perhaps your shell just needs to notice it; does running `rehash` fix things? If not, what does `file /usr/bin/cabal` say? If it says it is a shell script or similar, what is the contents of `/usr/bin/cabal`?

Comment: rehash - command not found.

Comment: @DanielWagner, $ file /usr/bin/cabal
/usr/bin/cabal: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=52e0a2baaf74ac55bcb271d2fa8f10d7c3527f1f, stripped

Comment: Oops, in bash, `rehash` is spelled `hash -r`. Sorry about that, zsh junkie here.